# Count the number of people for a period with a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, distinct

We have a table with information about users in the course.

```
CREATE TABLE public.students
(
    student_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('students_student_id_seq'::regclass),
    timest timestamp without time zone NOT NULL   ##
    is_correct BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT students_pkey PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
)
```

A 'successful' student who at least once in the current month correctly done 10 exercises in an hour.
Help a query that will give information on the number of successful students for October 2020.

Tried to find the number of continuously solved exercises in an hour. For this, I calculated the commutative sum which less 3600.

```
WITH timediff AS (
     SELECT *,
         LEAD(timest) OVER w AS next_time,
         LEAD(timest) OVER w - timest AS diff
     FROM payment
     WHERE is_correct IS TRUE
     WINDOW w AS (PARTITION  BY student_id ORDER BY timest 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))

SELECT *,
    CASE  
    WHEN (sum(diff) OVER q) > '3600' 
    THEN diff 
    ELSE (sum(diff) OWER q) 
    END cum_sum
FROM timediff
WINDOW q AS (PARTITION  by student_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Then I don’t know how to count continuous periods. I think this is not the best option.
Please help with your request.

Comment: The code is clearly Postgres so I removed the SQL Server tag.  Sample data and desired results would also make your question much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A 'successful' student who at least once in the current month correctly done 10 exercises in an hour.

If I follow you correctly, you can use window functions and a range frame:

```
select count(distinct student_id) cnt_successful_students
from (
    select s.*,
        count(*) filter(where is_correct) over(
            partition by student_id 
            order by timest
            range between interval '1 hour' preceding and current row
        ) cnt
    from students s
    where timest >= date_trunc('month', current_date) 
      and timest <  date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month'
) s
where cnt >= 10
```

The subquery filters on the current month. For each row, the window function count how many successful exercice the same student took during the last hour. The outer query then filters on students that reached the threshold at least once.